# Robots.txt for a multilanguage site where root is redirected

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I have a site which offers two languages, English and Spanish. When the user navigates to the home page, let's say `www.example.com` the page redirects you to either `/es` if your browser language is Spanish or English otherwise.

At the moment the `robots.txt` I have is:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

because I'm defining all `hreflang` `alternate` URLs in the `sitemap_languages.xml` and all URLs are listed also in the `sitemap.xml`. My question is more towards the configuration of the `robots.txt` because I'm not sure if I should be allowing any user agent to crawl the `/` page. As that page always redirects to the home of either `/en` or `/es` I believe that should be disallowed.

Should I then do:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /es
Allow: /en

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

I'm not sure if that could cause a crawl issue or whether there is another way to achieve the same result.

Comment: What do you show on the root if the browser does not have a language set?  What if the `Accept-Language` header is not included in the request?  What if the user's preferred language is something other than English or Spanish? The best way to handle that is to show a "choose your language" page.  Do you do that?

Comment: My fallback is to the Spanish root

Comment: And what is somebody is browsing the "wrong" language?   If the browser is set to English, but they are on your Spanish site, do you allow that?

Comment: I do allow browsing on both languages. This is just to automate the language selection if available when they initially navigate to the website. You can swap languages at any time. I mean you can check it by yourself : www.topyco.com

Comment: _Aside:_ "fallback is to the Spanish root", although your question text appears to state the opposite: "to either /es if your browser language is Spanish or _English otherwise_"? Presumably, you don't actually have a _space_ in the sitemap URL in your `robots.txt` file? ie. `Sitemap: https:// www.example.com/...`?

Comment: Just a suggestion... "You can swap languages at any time.". However, if I manually select "Spanish" (after being redirected automatically to English) and later manually navigate back to the site root, I am automatically redirected back to English again. Maybe set an overriding cookie if the user has manually selected an alternative language?

Comment: Re the space, no, this was to allow me post a “url” in the question

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas When the text is formatted as "code" (either inline with backticks or indented code block - as you have done) then there is no restriction on posting "URLs", since it's seen as just plain text, not a URL.

Comment: Cool, somehow I wasn’t able to submit that with the urls and I had to put the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this situation is to allow crawling of the root page, but to show a page with links to all languages when the `Accept-Language` header is not present or does not match one of your supported languages.    Web crawlers typically crawl without an `Accept-Language` header and they will almost always get this page.

That will allow search engines to pass link juice to your site appropriately.  If you disallow crawling on your root page, you are throwing away the link juice from all links to the root.  Typically sites get more links to the root than any where else.

Disallowing crawling won't prevent the root URL from getting indexed.   Google will include disallowed pages in the index if they have links to them.  When that happens Google will show unfriendly messages such as "A snippet cannot be shown because the page was blocked by robots.txt."  It is far better to let the search engines crawl the page and see what is actually there.

The page can be quite simple:

```
<title>example.com</title>
<a href=/es>Español</a> | <a href=/en>English</a>
```

Most users won't see it, they will be automatically redirected away from it if they land on that URL.   Search engine crawlers will get the links they need to crawl both languages and assign link juice to them.

In your sitemap the root page should be listed as `x-default`:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/es"/>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/en</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/es"/>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/es</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/es"/>
</url>
```

It is good that you allow people to view any language based on the URL regardless of their browser setting.  That is especially important to web crawlers.  If you were to redirect away from URLs based on `Accept-Language` it would make your site uncrawable by search engine spiders.

Comment: Many thanks for the great explanation and suggestion. I have a question though. If the user types “example” in google and searches that term, would the example.com page will get displayed? I say that just to confirm I won’t have any issues in terms of SERP results. Thanks again!!

Comment: Because of the alternate hreflang in the sitemap and the lack of content on the page, it would not usually get displayed in the search results.   There are some rare circumstances in which it could appear, however if a user clicks on it they will get taken to the right place.

Comment: Ok, I’ll give it a go, thanks. On the other hand, what about the canonical URL? Should I use one canonical ver version of the site or should I pick one? After reading several posts about canonical and hreflang some people do just one language as canonical and some other do a canonical pero version (language)

Comment: I always use different canonical URLs per language.

Comment: Hi Stephen, just wanted to say thanks for your help as all the changes you suggested plus some others I made fixed the at issue. Many thanks!